# OneToMany field in Odoo proper way to link two models

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

```
    raise UserError(_("No inverse field %r found for %r") % (self.inverse_name, self.comodel_name))
odoo.exceptions.UserError: ("No inverse field None found for 'res.sector'", '' )
```

I'm trying to create a new model and having problems linking it to another model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably declared a [One2many](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/developer/reference/addons/orm.html#odoo.fields.One2many) field like following:

```
field_name = fields.One2many('res.sector')
```

You need to specify the inverse name (mandatory), the name of a `Many2one` field declared in `res.sector` that reference the model where you declared the `One2many` field.

Comment: Well the error was that I declared the inverse field in the wrong model and didn't notice (declared it twice), and I thought the error that kept coming up was do to my other declaration whilst it was correct.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you need to specify an inverse name on the relation.

For example: (workcenter_id) is the inverse field

```
equipment_ids = fields.One2many('maintenance.equipment', 'workcenter_id')
```